# Recover data if PC (motherboard) fails with software RAID 5

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid, data-recovery, software-raid

I'm planning to implement a RAID 5 (or 6) system on an old PC (windows or linux). 
It doesn't have HW RAID 5 support so I'll do it via software (e.g. windows integrated RAID).

Will I be able to recover my data in case my motherboard fails?
(without buying an identical motherboard)
And if it is the Operating System Hard Drive that fails?

I searched the web and found that with HW RAID is very difficult to recover from an HW fails. I hope SW RAID will be more flexible.

Thank you very much.

Ps: I know that RAID is not backup but I can't afford backup right now. I think that for me raid is better than no protection.

Comment: You should always backup your data.

Comment: [Maybe... Maybe Not. Raid protects against disk failure, not mobo failure.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21054888/17413)

Comment: If you're going to use 4 or so drives for raid, you're better off using some of those drives for *actual* backup, and designing around failure tolerance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed: snapraid!

Basically is backup using raid 5. You can only do snapshots but it serves my purpose. 
You can recover data in the event of motherboard and\or disk failure (i checked by myself).

Thank you to everyone!